# in Swift, on Firestore, is it possible to query the user ID in 2 fields of each document?

Tags: swift, firebase, snapshot

In Firestore, is it possible today to query an ID in two fields with "or?

here is my struct:

```
struct Invitations: Codable {
    
    enum EtatDeValidationDeLInvitation: String, Codable {
        case encours
        case accepter
    }
    
    var idenvoyeur = ""
    var idreceveur = ""
    var datedelenvoi : Date = Date()
    var statutdelinvitation : EtatDeValidationDeLInvitation = .encours
    
}
```

I need to do something like this:

```
db.collection("Invitations").whereField("idenvoyeur", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, or "idreceveur", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocuments { ...
```

I need to query where the ID of the user is in the documents of the collection "Invitations". He could be the "idenvoyeur" or the "idreceveur", or non of them.

I need to know if it is possible today on firestore, to query in all documents of a collection in order to retrieve some of them where the user is the sender or the receiver.

Comment: I would suggest just adding another property, an array, and store those two values also in the array. Then you can use a logical OR query on the array. See [Array Contains Any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any). Super simple solution.

Comment: @Jay Please read the answer below. It was already written. but for me, and i am a beginner, it was pretty difficult to find it by myself.

Comment: That code stores two values in an array but doesn't really address how to query that data in Firebase via `array contains any`. But it's going the right direction. A super answer would then be how to do that query. Where was this answer 'already written'. If it was here on SO, a link to it in comments or your question would be better than copy and pasting it as an answer (it's also incomplete as well as I mentioned)

Comment: @jay thank you. I just put the Firestore function that query in this array, and i have explained that i just need to know if the user is present in the array, and not if he is the sender or the receiver. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this solution:
i have to put a variable "participants" in the struct where i need to query:

```
struct EtatDesInvitations: Codable {
    
    enum EtatDeValidationDeLInvitation: String, Codable {
        case encours
        case accepter
    }
    
    var idenvoyeur = ""
    var idreceveur = ""
    var datedelenvoi : Date = Date()
    var statutdelinvitation : EtatDeValidationDeLInvitation = .encours
    
    var participants = [String]() //The solution
    
}
```

This variable is an array of string. it will contains all the elements where i need to query.
And here is the function to assign it values:

```
func arrayPourEtatDesInvitations(idenvoyeur: String, idreceveur: String, datedelenvoi: Date, statutdelinvitationrawvalue: String) -> [String] {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YY, MMM d, HH:mm:ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: datedelenvoi)
    
        var array = [String]()
        array.append(idenvoyeur)
        array.append(idreceveur)
        array.append(statutdelinvitationrawvalue)
        array.append(date)
    return array
}
```

So when i store an instance of my struct "Invitations", it will contains all the values of the fields where i need to query in the variable "participants".

```
db.collection("Invitations").whereField("participants", arrayContains: FireStoreClass.shared.currentUser.id).addSnapshotListener() { [weak self] (querySnapshotinvitations, error) in
```

For my case, i don't need to know if the user is the sender or the receiver. I juste need to know if his ID is present in this array.
This approach is working for me.